# ASP.NET Link Enter key with buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, webforms

I stumbled across a little problem with an ASP.NET Web Application.

I got a couple buttons on my page that I want to access by pressing my Enter key (Depending on which `TextBox` is focused).

Googled helped me, I thought, but no.

This is what I found:

```
tbEmail.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('" + btRegister.UniqueID + "').click();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
```

[Source](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Accept-Enter-Key.aspx)

This does not seem to work, it still presses another button that I do not want to be pressed at this moment.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you're using Web Forms.

You can wrap what you're doing inside of a `Panel` and set the `DefaultButton` property inside of the panel.

```xml
<asp:Panel ID="LoginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btLogin">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btLogin" runat="server">Login</asp:Button>
</asp:Panel>
```

When the user has entered data in either `txtUser` and `txtPass` and then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, they will trigger the button `btLogin`.

Comment: I was modifying the stock `Login.aspx` page and it works just as well there too. The button was missing ID property and CommandName was so was not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try and use the JavaScript - put your form inside an `<asp:Panel>` and set the `DefaultButton` property to be the id of your button.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery for this is much easier. Bind to [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event.

Comment: I agree.  jQuery encapsulates all those nasty details and is a godsend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, going to use this in the future for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keypress event for each textbox which will do different things.. so:

```
private void a_keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    RadTextBox myBox = (RadTextBox)sender;

    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        if (myBox.ID == "textbox1")
        // then do stuff...
    }
    else if //do stuff...
}
```